# "API MISUSE: Resurrection of an object"

Tags: objective-c, macos

My app is working normally for me and for almost all my users, but two of my users (both El Capitan users) reported a similar, but strange crash.

That's the exception:

```
Exception Type: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note: EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
API MISUSE: Resurrection of an object
```

And these are there respective crashed threads. From the first user:

```
Thread 11 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.user-initiated-qos
0 libdispatch.dylib 0x00007fff93e901b3 _os_object_retain + 45
1 com.apple.audio.CoreAudio 0x00007fff8c497063 void std::__1::vector >::__push_back_slow_path(CADispatchQueue::EventSource&&) + 243
2 com.apple.audio.CoreAudio 0x00007fff8c496ed6 CADispatchQueue::InstallMachPortDeathNotification(unsigned int, void () block_pointer) + 174
3 com.apple.audio.CoreAudio 0x00007fff8c492202 HALC_ProxyObject::HALC_ProxyObject(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int) + 154
4 com.apple.audio.CoreAudio 0x00007fff8c49e558 HALC_ProxyObjectMap::_CreateObject(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int) + 188
5 com.apple.audio.CoreAudio 0x00007fff8c491be8 HALC_ProxyObjectMap::_CopyObjectByObjectID(unsigned int) + 248
6 com.apple.audio.CoreAudio 0x00007fff8c491a47 HALC_ProxyObjectMap::CopyObjectByObjectID(unsigned int) + 67
7 com.apple.audio.CoreAudio 0x00007fff8c4a4998 HALC_ShellDevice::RebuildControlList(bool) + 478
8 com.apple.audio.CoreAudio 0x00007fff8c4b29b9 HALC_ShellDevice::_ProxyObject_GroupPropertiesChanged(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int const*, unsigned int, unsigned int const*, unsigned int, AudioObjectPropertyAddress const*) + 309
9 com.apple.audio.CoreAudio 0x00007fff8c4b287e ___ZN16HALC_ShellDevice34ProxyObject_GroupPropertiesChangedEjjPKjjS1_jPK26AudioObjectPropertyAddress_block_invoke + 60
10 com.apple.audio.CoreAudio 0x00007fff8c4a0913 HALB_CommandGate::ExecuteCommand(void () block_pointer) const + 33
11 com.apple.audio.CoreAudio 0x00007fff8c4b283c HALC_ShellDevice::ProxyObject_GroupPropertiesChanged(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int const*, unsigned int, unsigned int const*, unsigned int, AudioObjectPropertyAddress const*) + 102
12 com.apple.audio.CoreAudio 0x00007fff8c4b2775 ___ZN23HALC_ProxyNotifications27_SendGroupPropertiesChangedEjjPKjjS1_jPK26AudioObjectPropertyAddressb_block_invoke + 77
13 libdispatch.dylib 0x00007fff93e9b93d _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
14 libdispatch.dylib 0x00007fff93e9040b _dispatch_client_callout + 8
15 libdispatch.dylib 0x00007fff93e9429b _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 1890
16 libdispatch.dylib 0x00007fff93e93b00 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 91
17 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x00007fff8cdc44de _pthread_wqthread + 1129
18 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x00007fff8cdc2341 start_wqthread + 13
```

And from the second user:

```
Thread 14 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.user-initiated-qos
0 libdispatch.dylib 0x00007fff8f9be0e7 _os_object_retain + 45
1 com.apple.audio.CoreAudio 0x00007fff90d57063 void std::__1::vector >::__push_back_slow_path(CADispatchQueue::EventSource&&) + 243
2 com.apple.audio.CoreAudio 0x00007fff90d56ed6 CADispatchQueue::InstallMachPortDeathNotification(unsigned int, void () block_pointer) + 174
3 com.apple.audio.CoreAudio 0x00007fff90d52202 HALC_ProxyObject::HALC_ProxyObject(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int) + 154
4 com.apple.audio.CoreAudio 0x00007fff90d5e558 HALC_ProxyObjectMap::_CreateObject(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int) + 188
5 com.apple.audio.CoreAudio 0x00007fff90d51be8 HALC_ProxyObjectMap::_CopyObjectByObjectID(unsigned int) + 248
6 com.apple.audio.CoreAudio 0x00007fff90d51a47 HALC_ProxyObjectMap::CopyObjectByObjectID(unsigned int) + 67
7 com.apple.audio.CoreAudio 0x00007fff90d64998 HALC_ShellDevice::RebuildControlList(bool) + 478
8 com.apple.audio.CoreAudio 0x00007fff90d729b9 HALC_ShellDevice::_ProxyObject_GroupPropertiesChanged(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int const*, unsigned int, unsigned int const*, unsigned int, AudioObjectPropertyAddress const*) + 309
9 com.apple.audio.CoreAudio 0x00007fff90d7287e ___ZN16HALC_ShellDevice34ProxyObject_GroupPropertiesChangedEjjPKjjS1_jPK26AudioObjectPropertyAddress_block_invoke + 60
10 com.apple.audio.CoreAudio 0x00007fff90d60913 HALB_CommandGate::ExecuteCommand(void () block_pointer) const + 33
11 com.apple.audio.CoreAudio 0x00007fff90d7283c HALC_ShellDevice::ProxyObject_GroupPropertiesChanged(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int const*, unsigned int, unsigned int const*, unsigned int, AudioObjectPropertyAddress const*) + 102
12 com.apple.audio.CoreAudio 0x00007fff90d72775 ___ZN23HALC_ProxyNotifications27_SendGroupPropertiesChangedEjjPKjjS1_jPK26AudioObjectPropertyAddressb_block_invoke + 77
13 libdispatch.dylib 0x00007fff8f9c9871 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
14 libdispatch.dylib 0x00007fff8f9be33f _dispatch_client_callout + 8
15 libdispatch.dylib 0x00007fff8f9c21cf _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 1890
16 libdispatch.dylib 0x00007fff8f9c1a34 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 91
17 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x00007fff9766568f _pthread_wqthread + 1129
18 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x00007fff97663365 start_wqthread + 13
```

Basically they had the same crash, and it's related with CoreAudio, but I don't even use CoreAudio in my application. The only places in my application where sound is used are when I use a NSSound:

```
[[NSSound soundNamed:@"Pop"] play];
```

When I attribute a sound to a NSUserNotification:

```
notification.soundName = NSUserNotificationDefaultSoundName;
```

And when I add Microphone input to the screen record feature (mSession is an AVCaptureSession):

```
AVCaptureDevice *audioDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];
AVCaptureDeviceInput * audioInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:audioDevice error:nil];
if ([mSession canAddInput:audioInput]) [mSession addInput:audioInput];
```

However, none of these functions appear to have been called in that or in any other thread of the crash report.

I found a very similar Crash Report happening on Chromium:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=549667

According to the last message maybe it's related to audio devices being unplugged while the app is running. Somebody else had that bug? How can I solve it? Thanks in advance.

Some informations that I think might help:

- My OS X target version is 10.8
- It's using the 10.11 SDK
- It's using ARC

Answer (score 2):

It seems a bug in OS.
When draw out the earphone，Xcode or Chrome or some other apps may crash into “ HALC_ProxyObjectMap API MISUSE: Resurrection of an object”

Comment: So what should I do? Add a try/catch to main.m to make the app ignore that exception specifically?